# TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I would like to use TikZ matrices to for some drawings. I am currently using nodes and positioning them manually to simulate a tabular. That helps in positioning arrows and shading.

[image: TikZ matrix]

However, if I use something like the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=0,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\
1   & 3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The nodes' lower and upper borders do not overlap, resulting in a double border between nodes.

[image: Double border]

edit:
Jake suggested a very nice solution, using negative row separation `row sep`. That work very well for one column tables. But the columns are misaligned when there are more columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black},
space/.style={minimum height=1.5em,matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style={font=\ttfamily}}]

\matrix (first) [space, column 1/.style={font=\ttfamily},column 2/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\
1   & 3 \\
2   & 9 \\
};

\matrix (second) [right=of first, space, column 2/.style={minimum width=3em,nodes={cell,minimum width=3.5em}},column 3/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   &a  & 6 \\
1   &   & 3 \\
2   &c  & 9 \\
};

\matrix [right=of second, space, column 2/.style={minimum width=3em,nodes={cell,minimum width=3.5em}},column 3/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   &a  & 6 \\
1   &b  & 3 \\
2   &c  & 9 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea to make your examples full compilable documents, starting from `\documentclass`. Otherwise everyone who tries to compile the example first has to figure out what packages are needed (it's not immediately obvious that `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` is required here, for example), and then write an adequate `.tex` file.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. Matrix is also lacking. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you set `row sep` to `-\pgflinewidth`, the lines will overlap exactly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\   1   & 3 \\   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix of nodes]

In order to make sure that the cells align correctly horizontally, you need to make the `text height` and `text depth` the same across the entire row. By setting `nodes in empty cells`, all cells will be drawn, even if no content is provided. Alternatively, you can enter `{}` into empty cells to achieve the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black},
space/.style={minimum height=1.5em,matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style={font=\ttfamily}},text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex,nodes in empty cells]

\matrix (first) [space, column 1/.style={font=\ttfamily},column 2/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   & 6 \\   1   & 3 \\   2   & 9 \\   };

\matrix (second) [right=of first, space, column 2/.style={minimum width=3em,nodes={cell,minimum width=3.5em}},column 3/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   &a  & 6 \\   1   &   & 3 \\   2   &c  & 9 \\   };

\matrix [right=of second, space, column 2/.style={minimum width=3em,nodes={cell,minimum width=3.5em}},column 3/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=2em}}]
{
0   &a  & 6 \\   1   &b  & 3 \\   2   &c  & 9 \\   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix tables with fixed text depth and text height]

Comment: @Jake: A slight problem. What if some nodes are empty in a `matrix of nodes`. They then do not take up space, and various rows get misaligned.

Comment: @ipavlic: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you edit your question to include an example?

Comment: @ipavlic: This behaviour is not because of the empty nodes, but because of the differing text height and text depth in your number and text nodes. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jake: I understand now, and also found more details in the documentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jake, could you just include into your answer that when `{}` is inputed, the node is rendered with empty text. That is helpful when one wants to render all nodes, even the empty ones.

Comment: @ipavlic: You can use the `nodes in empty cells` key for this. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

For information, the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` creates tabulars similar to `{tabular}` but with PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. You can use those nodes with Tikz. However, you can also add rules in the tabular with the classical technics of `{tabular}` (eg: `\hline`).

In the following code, I have used the key `hvlines` which draws all the rules (excepted in the "first" column and "first" row).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\ttfamily}rc}[name=Left]
M         & \Block[draw]{} 0 \\
\\
L         & \Block[draw]{} 4 \\
\\
available & \Block[draw]{} 8 \\
\end{NiceTabular}\hspace{3cm}
\begin{NiceTabular}
  [
    first-col,
    code-for-first-col=\inteval{\value{iRow}-1},
    first-row,
    hvlines,
    color-inside,
    name = Right
  ]
  {cc}  
& element & next \\
& \cellcolor{gray!30}
          & $6$  \\
& 1       & $3$  \\
& b       & $9$  \\
&         & $5$  \\
& \cellcolor{gray!30}
          & $7$  \\
&         & $-1$ \\
&         & $10$ \\
& a       & $2$  \\
&         & $11$ \\
& c       & $-1$ \\
& c       & $-1$ \\
&         & $1$  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw [->] (Left-1.5-|Left-last) to [bend right] (Right-1.5-|Right-1) ; 
  \draw [->] (Left-3.5-|Left-last) to [bend left] (Right-5.5-|Right-1) ; 
  \draw [->] (Left-5.5-|Left-last) to [bend left] (Right-9.5-|Right-1) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Would you mind explaining what \ValueMinusOne tries to achieve, and where do Left-3.5, Left-last come from?

Comment: @greendiod: `\ValueMinusOne{n}` computes `n-1` . `Left` and `Right` are the names that I have decided to give to the environments `{NiceTabular}` that I have created (to give a name to a tabular, I have use the key `name` provided by `nicematrix`). `1.5`, `2.5` , `3.5`, etc. are numbers of the horizontal rules of the tabulars. In fact, when I write `3.5` (for instance), I specify the y-coordinate half-way between the horizontal rules 3 and 4 (that is to say the middle of the third row).

Comment: Thank you. I knew about east, west for nodes in the pgf/tikz last manual the last time I read it.  I didn't know that one could refer to half-way rows.  How would you specify x-coordinates? It's close to black magic! I'll check the 'nicematrix' package.

Comment: @greendiod: `(i-|j)` if the intersection of the horizontal rule number i and the vertical rule number j. You can use half values for both i and j (by design of `nicematrix`: this is not a general feature of Tikz).