# Color of square cell in array

Tags: tables, color

I would like to have array with square cells and fill cells with colors. There is done implementation of table with square cells by W. Robertson http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/robertson/robertson.pdf :

```
\newlength\celldim \newlength\fontheight \newlength\extraheight
\newcounter{sqcolumns}

\newcolumntype{S}{ @{}
  >{\centering \rule[-0.5\extraheight]{0pt}{\fontheight + \extraheight}}
  p{\celldim} @{} }

\newcolumntype{Z}{ @{} >{\centering} p{\celldim} @{} }

\newenvironment{squarecells}[1]
  {\setlength\celldim{2em}%
  \settoheight\fontheight{A}%
  \setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}%
  \setcounter{sqcolumns}{#1 - 1}%
  \begin{tabular}{|S|*{\value{sqcolumns}}{Z|}}\hline}
  % squarecells tabular goes here
  {\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\nl{\tabularnewline\hline}
```

So I write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\celldim \newlength\fontheight \newlength\extraheight
\newcounter{sqcolumns}

\newcolumntype{S}{ @{}
  >{\centering \rule[-0.5\extraheight]{0pt}{\fontheight + \extraheight}}
  p{\celldim} @{} }

\newcolumntype{Z}{ @{} >{\centering} p{\celldim} @{} }

\newenvironment{squarecells}[1]
  {\setlength\celldim{4em}%
  \settoheight\fontheight{A}%
  \setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}%
  \setcounter{sqcolumns}{#1 - 1}%
  \begin{tabular}{|S|*{\value{sqcolumns}}{Z|}}\hline}
  % squarecells tabular goes here
  {\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\nl{\tabularnewline\hline} 

\begin{document}

\begin{squarecells}{4}
\cellcolor{red}16 & 3 & 2 & 13 \nl
5 & 10 & 11 & 8 \nl
9 & 6 + 2 & 7 & 12 \nl
4 & 15 & 14 & 1 \nl
\end{squarecells}

\end{document}
```

Output is:

[image: Output]

Cell is filled with red color a little more than it should be. Question is, how to properly fill cell with color? Or maybe is there some other good solution to create table with square cells?

Comment: Can you make your code into a compilable document, instead of just fragments.

Comment: it's done now..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're not set on the `array` approach and would be okay with explicitly specifying the size of the squares, you could use TikZ for this. Based on the answer to the question [TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular/18524#18524), you could define a `style` that adjusts a TikZ `matrix` to have all the cells join each other and have identical heights and widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
16 & 3 & 2 & 13 \\
5 & 10 &|[fill=yellow]| 11 & 8 \\
9 & 6 + 2 & 7 & 12 \\
4 & 15 & 14 & 1 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz matrix with square elements]

To adjust the size of the elements, use `square matrix=<length>`. To fill elements with different colours, use `|[fill=<colour>]|` in the cell you want to adjust.

Comment: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to 
ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. -- When I remove align, then numbers are aligned to left-bottom corner.

Comment: @scdmb: You're using an old version of TikZ (v 2.0, probably?), the current one is v 2.1

Comment: @scdmb: Try changing `text width=#1` to `minimum width=#1`, that should work with the old version as well.

Comment: @Jake is this answer updated? Because in `beamer` I cannot test with `\matrix`, it throws me a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1):

If, in your code, I replace `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` (of `nicematrix`, which I have loaded) with the key `color-inside` (alias: `colortbl-like`), I have directly the expected output. The reason is that `nicematrix` colors the cells by using PGF/Tikz under the hood and do not use `colortbl`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\celldim \newlength\fontheight \newlength\extraheight
\newcounter{sqcolumns}

\newcolumntype{S}{ @{}
  >{\centering \rule[-0.5\extraheight]{0pt}{\fontheight + \extraheight}}
  p{\celldim} @{} }

\newcolumntype{Z}{ @{} >{\centering} p{\celldim} @{} }

\newenvironment{squarecells}[1]
  {\setlength\celldim{4em}%
  \settoheight\fontheight{A}%
  \setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}%
  \setcounter{sqcolumns}{#1 - 1}%
  \begin{NiceTabular}[color-inside]{|S|*{\value{sqcolumns}}{Z|}}\hline}
  % squarecells tabular goes here
  {\end{NiceTabular}}

\newcommand\nl{\tabularnewline\hline} 

\begin{document}


\begin{squarecells}{4}
\cellcolor{red}16 & 3 & 2 & 13 \nl
5 & 10 & 11 & 8 \nl
9 & 6 + 2 & 7 & 12 \nl
4 & 15 & 14 & 1 \nl
\end{squarecells}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]