# confusion matrix using only LaTeX code

Tags: tables, matrices

I need to make a table in this specific format

[image]

The main problem is that I do not want to use any other package and want to do it in only latex code!

Note: I found a related question but it uses `TikZ` to solve the problem. However I want pure latex code only.

Comment: May I ask why you want it to be pure (La)TeX?

Comment: Confusion matrix is new to me. Do you mean `correlation matrix`?

Comment: This is related, but uses packages: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172578/simplest-way-to-create-a-grid-with-colored-squares-and-labels.  My answer there uses `xcolor`, `graphicx`, and `stackengine`, but not `tikz`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Confusion matrix is used in binary machine learning classification problems / medical diagnosis and show frequencies of true positive, false positive, false negative and false positive cases and the subtotal tallies for a classifier or diagnosis method.

Answer (score 3):

Just [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to rotate the "Source2" label:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr1.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[4]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}\MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#3}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#4}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
}  

\begin{document}

{
\offinterlineskip
\raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c][0pt][c]{1cm}{\textbf{Source2}\\[20pt]}}}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr5.1cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Source1}\par
\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{A}\MyHBox{B}\MyHBox{C}\par
\MyTBox{A}{0.1}{0.3}{0.5}
\MyTBox{B}{0.5}{0.2}{0.1}
\MyTBox{C}{0.4}{0.7}{0.2}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't claim this is a very good solution, but the built-in `picture` can be used for this. I did use `graphicx` for `\rotatebox` though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(4,4)
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(0,1){4}{\line(1,0){3}}
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(1,0){4}{\line(0,1){3}}
\put(0.5,0.5){1}
\put(1.5,0.5){2}
\put(2.5,0.5){3}

\put(0.5,1.5){4}
\put(1.5,1.5){5}
\put(2.5,1.5){6}

\put(0.5,2.5){7}
\put(1.5,2.5){8}
\put(2.5,2.5){9}

\put(-0.5,2.5){A}
\put(-0.5,1.5){B}
\put(-0.5,0.5){C}

\put(0.5,3.5){A}
\put(1.5,3.5){B}
\put(2.5,3.5){C}

\put (-1.2,1.5){\rotatebox{90}{Text}}
\put(1.2,4.2){Text}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```