# Centering a group of raiseboxes from example

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, matrices

With respect to this link: [confusion matrix using only LaTeX code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271465/confusion-matrix-using-only-latex-code), which was very helpful, I was able to reduce the example to a 2x2 matrix, however when trying to center the whole structure, the y-axis label is centered independent from the rest of the table structure.

[image]

This was done by encapsulating the table in a figure, and subsequently centering environment. My question is now, how can I center the table as whole?

I wish to be able to place the table in its entirety where I want and add both labels and captions as well if possible.

**Edit:** Added example code. Also included all packages used since I'm not sure whether these wel affect possible solutions.

```
%%%% Add Packages %%%%
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%% Confusion Matrix Body %%%%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
  % Size of boxes
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr1.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[4]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}
  \MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#3}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}%
}  
%%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
{

\offinterlineskip

\raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c][0pt][c]{0cm}{\textbf{Actual}\\[20pt]}}}\par

\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr3.4cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Predicted}\par

\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{30}\MyHBox{90}\par

\MyTBox{30}{9418}{1471}

\MyTBox{90}{144}{317}

}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  The cause of your problem will likely be explained by the code which generates the problem, please provide an MWE so we can see how you reach the faulty output.

Comment: Fair enough! I've edited the question once more. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside `figure` or another floating environment.

Answer (score 2):

I have edit your source add a macro `\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}` and `\parbox[c][0pt][c]{0cm}{\hspace{-3.5cm}\rot{\textbf{Actual}}\\[20pt]}}\par`.
I hope to have resolve your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%% Confusion Matrix Body %%%%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
  % Size of boxes
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr1.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[4]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}
  \MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#3}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}%
}  
%%%%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
{

\offinterlineskip

\raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{
\parbox[c][0pt][c]{0cm}{\hspace{-3.5cm}\rot{\textbf{Actual}}\\[20pt]}}\par

\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr3.4cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Predicted}\par

\hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{30}\MyHBox{90}\par

\MyTBox{30}{9418}{1471}

\MyTBox{90}{144}{317}

}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should open another thread for this but I was wondering if it is also possible to place two of these horizontally next to each other without messing the figure up. I tried to use the subfig package and included the two figures both in a subfloat{} environment. This did not work unfortunately.