# 2x2 Confusion Matrix

Tags: labels

Hello I would like to construct a Confusion Matrix as described here:
[confusion matrix using only LaTeX code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271465/confusion-matrix-using-only-latex-code?rq=1)

[image]

Unfortunately I have failed to adjust the code :(

I got as close as [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350019/centering-a-group-of-raiseboxes-from-example), but the labels "actual" & "predicted" are not really centred.
[image]

Can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It looks like you've simply copied the image from the other answer.  Can you at least expand that source to get the 3x3 matrix?  We like to see at least some sort of attempt on this site.

Answer (score 4):

After a coffee break I was able to answer it. :D

Still thank you for your help!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}

%%%% Confusion Matrix Body %%%%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
    \fbox{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{3cm}{\centering #1}}%
    % Size of boxes
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
    \parbox[c][1cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}  
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr3cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
    \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}  
\newcommand\MyTBox[4]{%
    \MyVBox{#1}
    \MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
    \MyBox{#3}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}%
}  
%%%%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{TP}{True Positive}
    \acro{FP}{False Positive}
    \acro{TN}{True Negative}
    \acro{FN}{False Negative}
\end{acronym}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    {

        \offinterlineskip

        \raisebox{-6cm}[0pt][0pt]{
            \parbox[c][5pt][c]{1cm}{\hspace{-4.1cm}\rot{\textbf{Actual}}\\[20pt]}}\par

        \hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr3.4cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Predicted}\par

        \hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{Cancelled}\MyHBox{Not Cancelled}\par

        \MyTBox{\rot{Cancelled}}{\ac{TP}}{\ac{FN}}

        \MyTBox{\rot{Not Cancelled}}{\ac{FP}}{\ac{TN}}

    }
\end{center}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Because I am interested is there a better way to make Actual aligned in the middle with the same distance as Predicted. (My solution was try and error)

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below code meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Source1}}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{B}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C}}\\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Source2}}}}
&\textbf{A} &0.1 &0.3 &0.5\\
\cline{3-5}
&\textbf{B} &0.5 &0.2 &0.1\\
\cline{3-5}
&\textbf{C} &0.4 &0.7 &0.2\\
\cline{3-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: This isn't a 2x2 confusion matrix though

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Predicted}}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}{\textbf{0}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1}}\\
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{True}}}}
&\textbf{0} &0.1 &0.3\\
\cline{3-4}
&\textbf{1} &0.5 &0.2\\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).