# Creating a heatmap using calculations and tabular environment

Tags: macros, color, calculations, colortbl, fp

I know there exists pgf, and many people uses this to create heatmaps. I however am not allowed to use this package. I therefore want to create a command that enables me to color the different cells.

I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154427/48108), that showed the following `def`

```
\def\cca#1{\cellcolor{black!#10}\ifnum #1>5\color{white}\fi{#1}}
```

But it does only work from 0-9 as per his comments and my tests.

I wanted to create something more generic like this pseudo code:

```
\newcommand{\cTab}[2]
{
    \res = #1/#2 %maybe using FP (?)
    \eighty = 0.8*#2 %maybe using FP (?)

    \cellcolor{black!\res} 
    \ifnum #1>\eighty 
       \color{white}
    \fi{#1}
}
```

So basicly the issue is to calculate a number and then reuse it to define color and other?

I can calculate the number using FP, but not reuse it within `cellcolor` or `ifnum`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt]{article}

% Color
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{True data classification.}
\label{tab:CollectedErrors}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Exposure}& \textbf{Attribute} \\ \hline

  4 & 2 \\ \hline
   11 &144 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Basicly what I want is to create a heatmap, i.e. color cells based on the number within the cell in the table.

**MWE using code from solution 1**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt]{article}

% Color
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}%
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand{\cTab}[2]
{%
    \edef\res    {\xinttheiexpr [2] #1/#2\relax}% [2] = "two digits after ."
    \edef\eighty {\xinttheiexpr [2] 0.8*#2\relax}%
    \cellcolor{black!\res}%
    \xintifboolexpr {#1>\eighty}
        % yes branch 
           {\color{white}}
        % no branch (nothing to do)
           {}% 
    {#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{True data classification.}
\label{tab:CollectedErrors}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Exposure}& \textbf{Attribute} \\ \hline

  \cTab{4}{4} & 2 \\ \hline %example, could also be \cTab{4}{144}, in theory all cells should be changed to cTab
   11 &144 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifnum` does only work for integer numbers,not for floating point

Comment: I don't know if you are tied to `tabular` or not, but here are two questions that show other approaches:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172578/simplest-way-to-create-a-grid-with-colored-squares-and-labels and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have been told that I am constrained by the tabular environment, unfortunately. I found many other examples as you also mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand{\cTab}[2]
{%
    \edef\res    {\xinttheiexpr [2] #1/#2\relax}% [2] = "two digits after ."
    \edef\eighty {\xinttheiexpr [2] 0.8*#2\relax}%
    \cellcolor{black!\res}%
    \xintifboolexpr {#1>\eighty}
    % yes branch 
       {\color{white}}
    % no branch (nothing to do)
       {}% 
    {#1}%
}%
```

But a mwe would help. Ok, mwe showed I needed `\xdef\res` but I am quite in the dark about what is aimed at. Update to explain I better understand now... (I was confused about `xcolor` color specification with a `!` as I was led to believe it needed a number between 0 and 1, whereas a percentage between 0 and 100 is asked for).

*Updated to avoid defining macros `\res` and `\eighty` (especially `\res` was annoying as it needed a global scope; but we can use expandability of `\xinttheiexpr` here).*

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt]{article}

% Color
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

% Fine stuff
\usepackage{xintexpr, xinttools}

\newcommand{\cTab}[2]% #1 = cell, #2 = max
{%
    \cellcolor{black!\xinttheiexpr 100*#1/#2\relax}%
    \xintifboolexpr {#1>0.8*#2}%
    % "yes" branch 
       {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}% when #1 is big, print it blue
    % "no" branch
       {#1}% 
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{True data classification.}
\label{tab:CollectedErrors}
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Exposure}& \textbf{Attribute} \\ \hline
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq[3]{1}{100}}\do
{%
  \cTab{#1}{100} & \cTab{\the\numexpr100-#1\relax}{100}\\
}
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Notice also the use of `\textcolor`.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: a mwe, what do you mean ? Your example seems to be exactly what I want. I will try this now.

Comment: a minimal working example means a small document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which one can copy paste and check. I have no idea where your command `\cTab` is used ...

Comment: I have updated the question with a MWE now. Furthermore I tested the solution by changing one cell and inserting another value, but I get an error: ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> black!\res \cTab{4}{4} & 

I have seen the other solution that refers to a \def instead of a command, I do not know if this is needed within a tabular environment?

Comment: your mwe does not show `\cTab` and where it is supposed to be use. Can you post the code which leads to the error you mention ?

Comment: I have created a MWE with the code and everything

Comment: Indeed you guessed right that the `\def` was not enough there (it is the same as  `\newcommand*`, basically) due to tabular. But it is still not quite clear what you want.

Comment: there is something fishy with your `\color{red!\res}` but don't have time to check now.

Comment: Lets imagine the I have a large table of lot of number ranging from 1 to 1000. A user in a large table has hard time seeing which numbers are what. Therefore using cellcolor, the user can see the darker the cell the higher the number, this is the basic goal. I therefore need to specify for each cell the cell number and the maximum number of all the cells (1000, from the example here). THen the function should fill that particular cell with the correct graident. Is this more clear?

Comment: all the cells are independent it is just a heatmap I want to create.

Comment: Your solution works now, I just edited some small stuff.

Comment: @JTIM yes, I understand now. Will try to update with a better example. If you needed the tabular to determine itself the maximum number inside the cells, that would make for another interesting question ... ;-)

Comment: From your code I thought you wanted `black!0.66`  but checking `xcolor` I see that `black!66` is what you want.

Comment: yeah sorry, my pseudo code was too pseudo :) But at least that helped a lot !! If you want to battle with the other question I will be more than happy to ask it :) It would be cool to have. But I am unsure how to do it without building at least two times?

Comment: It depends on the mark-up. For example `\DoRows{1&2\\3&4\\5&6}` could first compute the max, then produce the rows.

Comment: that is of course true, the issue is that then it should also be scalable for not only rows, but also columns. My limited coding experience in latex, I cannot say if it would be hard or easy :) But if you are up for the challenge, I am up for "trying" to formulate a better question with that as a goal :)

Comment: Please look at simplified `\cTab` macro. No need to define `\res` and `\eighty` anymore.

Comment: Cool much more simple. The reason for removing the defines is speed or?

Comment: speed is hardly an issue, but `\res` was a problem because it appeared that it had to be defined in a "global" way. Then we should have chosen a better name, for example with `@` sign, to reduce chances of overwriting some `\res` macro used elsewhere in the document. We can make do without ever defining `\res` because macro  `\xinttheiexpr` has the "expandability" property which allows it to be used almost everywhere in TeX without hickups.

Comment: side note: please note the use of `\textcolor`. A `\color{blue}` as in your original code adds some unwanted vertical space due to rather deep TeXnical things.