# transform simple matrix to simple picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Assume I have a very simple file with a matrix like

```
00011000
00022000
00011000
12100121
12100121
00011000
00022000
00011000
```

I want to import it to TikZ and transform it to a picture, where each cell
in the matrix is interpreted as a small square with a color, defined by the
content of the cell (e.g. 0 white, 1 gray, 2 black or so). I think that
there is a quite simple solution for it. Probably I do not need a complete
solution, some hints should be sufficient. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172578/simplest-way-to-create-a-grid-with-colored-squares-and-labels

Comment: Yes, 157080 seems to be the right way. I will test it with my 60x80 size matrix. Many thanks for the quick answer.