# Color cell/row/column in a table - De Gruyter

Tags: tables, color

I am using [De Gruyter template](https://www.degruyter.com/staticfiles/pdfs/AUTH_DG_LaTeX-Template.zip)
which redefines the `tabular` command so that it uses basically `booktabs` commands.

It is possible to turn this feature off using the command `\baretabulars`, but it seems that the commands to color the table do not make any effect: `\cellcolor`, `\rowcolor` and `\columncolor`. For example, the following table does not display any color.

```
\begin{baretabulars}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
\hline
\rowcolor{red} 1 & 2 \\
\hline 
3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{baretabulars}
```

I wonder if it is possible to color a table using the command `\baretabulars` since I want my table with vertical lines.

I am sorry if this question is not in the right standards.

Comment: Welcome to  TeX.SE! Please provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small, complete and compilable document), which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: booktabs rules and coloured cells, rows or columns do not work nicely together. The link is to a commercial available book (€99) so I assume we have to shell out that amount to be able to help you. You may contact the author of the book.

Comment: @Sveinung Thank you for the reply. I don't really know what happened, but I am almost sure I inserted another link. But anyways, I have updated the link, but it seems De Gruyter removed it. Yesterday was working. Is it possible to upload here the sty file?

Comment: Since this is a commercial book, and the style file is not published at CTAN, I assume they are copyrighted. You have to check with the author and publisher what you can and cannot do.

Comment: OK Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

For those who will have the same problem as me, I found a workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18755/color-of-square-cell-in-array) for this. The idea is to use `tikzpicture` in order to produce a table. In my case, I wanted to create a Cayley table so it suits me well. So adjusting the code for my example we would have something like:

```
\begin{baretabulars}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=2pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=0.45cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
|[fill=red]|1 & |[fill=red]|2 \\
3 & 4 \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{baretabulars}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is useless. We can't test it since `baretabulars` is not defined.