# Horizontal row separation line in tikz matrix (like \hline in tabular)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, nodes, matrices

In this question [tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular) a nice solution was given to let the matrix in tikz behave like tabular.

In this solution     `cell/.style={rectangle}` was used to draw lines around every cell. But usually, however, I'd rather not give my tables this "grid"-look.

Is there a way within the tikz matrix to draw horizontal lines between rows that essentially behave like `\hline` within tabular?

I know I could put a node in the first and final cell of a row and draw a line between them, but this is not really handy compared to a single command like `\hline` and not very automated either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a style that uses `execute at end cell` to draw a horizontal line at the top or bottom edge of selected cells. By applying this style to complete using `row <number>/.style`, you can get an effect similar to `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{toprule/.style={%
        execute at end cell={%
            \draw [line cap=rect,#1] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.north west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.north east);%
        }
    },
    bottomrule/.style={%
        execute at end cell={%
            \draw [line cap=rect,#1] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.south west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.south east);%
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,minimum width=3em,outer sep=0pt},
    row 1/.style={toprule=thick,bottomrule},
    row 3/.style={bottomrule=thick}]
{
0   & 6 & 5\\
1   & 3 & 7\\
21 & 22 & 23\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix of cells with horizontal lines]

Comment: A very nice solution. I like having the option to specify the line width. This gives the whole thing almost the feel of booktabs.

Answer (score 8):

The following might at least decrease the burden of putting the nodes etc. (I hope). In fact, it is similar to what you have already ruled out as a bad solution, but still it sweeps the ugliness under the rug and does not introduce new nodes other than the tikz `matrix` has already defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\hhlline}[3]{\draw (#1-#2-1.south west) -- (#1-#2-#3.south east);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[matrix of math nodes] (mymat) {
0   &a  & 6 \\
1   &b  & 3 \\
2   &c  & 9 \\
};
\hhlline{mymat}{1}{2};
\hhlline{mymat}{2}{3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, you use the command `\hhlline` with three arguments, the name of the matrix, the row you want to draw the line under it and the number of columns you want to keep drawing.

I am pretty sure that this can further be improved but I am not very good at accessing the internal variables of the matrix environment and using it inside the command automatically.  Anyway, hope it helps. Cheers

And last minute addition: Jake's solution looks quite nice.

Answer (score 8):

There is an issue with Jake's code if the nodes are different sizes.  This can be fixed using the `matrixcells` part of the TeX-SX TikZ package (currently available from [launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development)) to put the lines in after the matrix has been drawn and positioned correctly.  Here's a sample of the code, including an example showing where Jake's code breaks down.

Result:

[image: hlines and tikz matrices]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{matrixcells}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{toprule/.style={%
        execute at end cell={%
            \draw [line cap=rect,#1] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.north west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.north east);%
        }
    },
    bottomrule/.style={%
        execute at end cell={%
            \draw [line cap=rect,#1] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.south west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.south east);%
        }
    },
}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    hlines/.style={%
      label cells,
      initialise hlines,
      append after command={%
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\hline@cols}{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn - 1}}%
        \ifx\hline@rows\pgfutil@empty
        \else
        \foreach \hline@row in \hline@rows {
          \pgfextra{\edef\hline@temp{
          (\tikzlastnode-cell-\hline@row-1.north west) edge[\csname hline@row@\hline@row\endcsname] (\tikzlastnode-cell-\hline@row-\hline@cols.north east)}}
          \hline@temp
        }
        \fi
      }
    },
    initialise hlines/.code={
      \global\let\hline@rows=\pgfutil@empty
      \let\hline=\hline@inmatrix
    }
}

\newcommand\hline@inmatrix[1][]{%
    \ifx\hline@rows\pgfutil@empty
     \xdef\hline@rows{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}%
    \else
     \xdef\hline@rows{\hline@rows,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\xdef\csname hline@row@\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\endcsname{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={rectangle,minimum width=3em,outer sep=0pt},
    row 1/.style={toprule=thick,bottomrule},
    row 3/.style={bottomrule=thick}] (a)
{
\(\frac12\)   & 6 & 5\\
1   & 3 & 7\\
21 & 22 & 23\\
};
\matrix [matrix of nodes,hlines,anchor=north] (mm) at (a.south)
{
\(\frac12\)   & 6 & 5\\ \hline[thick]%
1   & 3 & 7\\ \hline
21 & 22 & 23\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I love it when solutions to different problems play together like that. Very nice!

Comment: A good hint, thanks for investigating this further

Comment: I can't reproduce this code. I get an error stating that `Command \hline@inmatrix already defined.`, and the two lines are striking through rows 2 and 3, rather than sitting in between.

Answer (score 1):

For information, the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` creates a tabular similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates a PGF/Tikz nodes under the content of each cell (and creates also PGF/Tikz nodes de type `coordinate` corresponding to the position of the potential rules).

Thus, it's possible to add rules with the technics of the classical `{tabular}` and access each cell as a PGF/Tikz node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[name=A]
\toprule
one & two & three \\
\midrule
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\hspace{2cm}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,name=B]
one & two & three \\
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine 
\end{NiceTabular}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [red,thick,->] (A-2-2) to [bend left] (B-2-2) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tiks nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you.

Comment: However, I have a small problem when it comes to the caption. I have insert my tikzpicture (who overlayes a given NiceTabular) inside a table environment to have a 'Table' caption. The latter is printed in the page previous to the one on which the table is...

Comment: @Wallflower: You should present your problem in a dedicated question on TeX Stack Exchange. I fear that it will not possible to give you a good answer in the comments...