# Horizontal Line Separating Steps in Aligned Equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I have an equation that I'm trying to display with horizontal line separation. The result I'm looking for is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/horizontal-row-separation-line-in-tikz-matrix-like-hline-in-tabular), but I'm not sure how to apply it to my equation (below).

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x + 3& = &7\\
-3 & = &-3\\
x& = &4\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite easy, actually: `aligned` is a special form of `array`, so `\hline` works. But I suggest to load the package **booktabs**:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

...

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x + 3& = 7\\
\midrule
-3 & = -3\\
\midrule
x& = 4\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

`\midrule` produce better spacing than `\hline`.

`aligned` (like `align`) requires a `&` before the alignment point (usually a relation), but not after it.

As Herbert points out, the vertical spacing may be not optimal. In case this is a real problem, one can resort to `array` (this requires the **array** package):

```
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r>{{}}l}
x + 3& =  7 \\
\midrule
-3   & = -3 \\
\midrule
x    & = 4
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

The intercolumn space is reduced to zero and before the relation symbol we put an empty group, so that TeX finds `{}=7` in the cell, that produces the correct horizontal spacing.

Comment: `\midrule` works great. Wondering if there is something that works as well in an `align` environment?

Comment: works with `\cline` or `\cmidrule` but has problems with vertical spacing

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
  \arraycolsep=1.4pt
\begin{array}{rl}\toprule[1pt]
x + 3& = 7     \\\midrule
-3 & = -3      \\\midrule
x& = 4         \\\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```