# Summation Subtraction Formatting

Tags: align

I am trying to stack two summations -- one on top of the other -- to illustarte term cancellation that takes place when subtracting the two sums.  I want the summations to align at the first "=" sign, be centered on the page, and also be underlined.  Here is as close as I've gotten:

```
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i =
        a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n =
        \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4$$

$$-\underline{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i = 
        a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1} =
        \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4}$$

$$a_n = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4 -
          \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4$$
```

Any ideas???

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic but, technically, these equations are incorrect as you are in effect writing `(A=B) - (C=D)` and it does't make much sense to subtract two equations like this. I think that what you want to write is `A-C = B-D = ...`.

Comment: Does any of these answers solve your issue? If yes, please accept the best that meet your requirements by clicking the check mark next to the answer. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is most likely a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/horizontal-line-separating-steps-in-aligned-equation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/horizontal-line-separating-steps-in-aligned-equation
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i &=
        a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n =
        \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4\\
-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i &= 
        -\left(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}\right) =
        -\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4\\
\midrule
a_n &= \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4 -
          \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{aligned}         
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is at least confusing; I’d add a minus sign also in the right hand side.

Comment: @egreg You're right. Grazie!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `align*` with the `amsmath` package. This keeps the spacing correct throughout, unlike the spacing created by making an array. You also have the option to number the rows by removing the `*`. Alignment is maintained using a `\phantom` command.

The horizontal line here is inserted as a `\rule` using `\intertext`. This can be automated using the `booktabs` package as others have mentioned.

[image]

Code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n &= \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4\\
-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i = a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}\phantom{{}+a_n} &= \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4\\
\intertext{\centering\rule{4.6in}{1pt}}
 a_n &=\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4-\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I suppose `\cdots` vs. `\ldots` is a personal preference.

Comment: Just use `\dots` for dots between alike symbols and `amsmath` will take care.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on the theme; I find that either you add a minus signs in front of each term in the second equation or in front of *none*. Just one minus sign is incorrect in all respects.

You can instead use words in order to help the reader in understanding what’s going on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

In order to compute $a_n$, subtract the
second equation from the first one:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i
 & = a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n
&& = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i
 & = a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}
&& = \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{alignedat}
\\
\midrule
a_n = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4
    - \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note. `\dots` should be used between alike symbols, in this case `+`; `amsmath` will take care of what kind of dots is needed. In case the dots are trailing, use `\dotsb` (like between binary symbols), `\dotsm` (like for multiplication), `\dotsi` (like between integrals), `\dotsc` (like between punctuation).

[image]

A different way to present the same argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

We have proved that, for every $n$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4.
\end{equation*}
Thus, for $n\ge1$, we can say
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i = \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{equation*}
which has the consequence that
\begin{equation*}
\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = 
a_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i = 
a_n+ \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4.
\end{equation*}
Hence, by comparing the first and the last terms,
\begin{equation*}
a_n=\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4-\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All answers here are LaTeX oriented but I am not able to read, that LaTeX is required from your answer. So, here is plain TeX solution:

```
In order to compute $a_n$, subtract the
second equation from the first one:
$$\eqalign{
   \sum_{i=1}^n a_i & = 
     a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n = \left[n(n+1)\over 2\right]^4
   \cr
   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i & = 
     a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}\phantom{{}+a_n}= \left[n(n-1)\over 2\right]^4
   \cr \noalign{\medskip\hrule\medskip}
   a_n & = \left[n(n+1)\over 2\right]^4 - \left[n(n-1)\over 2\right]^4
}
$$

\bye
```

Comment: `\frac` is not a plain TeX command. Nor is ConTeXt used, because it doesn't use `$$`.

Comment: @egreg `\frac` can be defined in plain TeX. We cannot see the whole document, so we cannot see this definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of this is to align term to term both sums, so one can show subtraction of summations more properly. For this, one can use an **array**.

By the way, to pursuing math accuracy, I included the needed `-` sign before all members of the equations in the second line (not only in the first member) and wrapped into parentheses the expanded sum.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{1pt}


\begin{document}

\subsection*{In-line math display}

\[
\begin{array}{rcrl}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i       &  =  &   a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-2} + a_{n-1} + a_n          & = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4 \\[2ex]
-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i    &  =  & - (a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-2} + a_{n-1})\hphantom{mm} & = -\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4 \\[2ex]\hline\\[-2ex]
                        &     &                                                 a_n     & = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4-\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip

\subsection*{Displaymath}
\[
\begin{array}{rcrl}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i    &  =  &   a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-2} + a_{n-1} + a_n          & = \left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4 \\[4ex]
\displaystyle-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i &  =  & -(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-2} + a_{n-1})\hphantom{mm}  & = -\left[\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4 \\[4ex]\hline\\[-1ex]
                                  &     &                                            a_n          & = \left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^4-\left[\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^4
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```