# How to draw complex nodes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know how to draw automaton in tikz. But how to use complex nodes in that? I want draw something like this in tikz:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you can do it with the `matrix` library:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   mymatrix/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=1.0cm,minimum height=1.0cm,inner sep=0,anchor=south west}
]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mymatrix] (firstmatrix) at (0,0)
    {   q & w & e \\
        a & s & d \\ 
    };
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mymatrix] (secondmatrix) at (10,0)
    {   i & o & p \\
        j & k & l \\ 
    };
    \draw[-latex] (firstmatrix.20) -- (secondmatrix.200);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** As *Altermundus* stated, the inner lines are double lines which is not desirable, so here's a solution using nodes and manually drawn lines (I'll try to automate this):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   mynode/.style={thick,minimum width=1.0cm,minimum height=1.0cm,inner sep=0,anchor=south west},
    mymatrix/.style={draw,inner sep=0}
]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, mymatrix] (firstmatrix) at (0,0)
    {   \node (q) {q}; & w & \node (e) {e}; \\
        \node (a) {a}; & s & \node (d) {d}; \\ 
    };
    \draw (q.south west) -- (e.south east);
    \draw (q.north east) -- (a.south east);
    \draw (e.north west) -- (d.south west);

    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, mymatrix] (secondmatrix) at (10,0)
    {   \node (i) {i}; & o & \node (p) {p}; \\
        \node (j) {j}; & k & \node (l) {l}; \\ 
    };
    \draw (i.south west) -- (p.south east);
    \draw (i.north east) -- (j.south east);
    \draw (p.north west) -- (l.south west);

    \draw[-latex] (firstmatrix.20) -- (secondmatrix.200);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 1.1:** As *Andrew Stacey* remarked, it is of cause not neccessary to explicitely put nodes. You're in a `matrix of nodes` Neo, and not a slave. The individual cells all have names of the form `matrixname-rownumber-columnnumber`, and one can use this. The following produces exactly the same result as before:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   mynode/.style={thick,minimum width=1.0cm,minimum height=1.0cm,inner sep=0,anchor=south west},
    mymatrix/.style={draw,inner sep=0},
    myline/.style={shorten <=0.2pt, shorten >=0.2pt},
]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, mymatrix] (firstmatrix) at (0,0)
    {   q & w & e \\
        a & s & d \\ 
    };
    \draw[myline] (firstmatrix-1-1.south west) -- (firstmatrix-1-3.south east);
    \draw[myline] (firstmatrix-1-1.north east) -- (firstmatrix-2-1.south east);
    \draw[myline] (firstmatrix-1-3.north west) -- (firstmatrix-2-3.south west);

    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, mymatrix] (secondmatrix) at (10,0)
    {   i & o & p \\
        j & k & l \\ 
    };
    \draw[myline] (secondmatrix-1-1.south west) -- (secondmatrix-1-3.south east);
    \draw[myline] (secondmatrix-1-1.north east) -- (secondmatrix-2-1.south east);
    \draw[myline] (secondmatrix-1-3.north west) -- (secondmatrix-2-3.south west);

    \draw[-latex] (firstmatrix.20) -- (secondmatrix.200);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 2:** Another way to "avoid" the double outline is to `draw` both the `node`s and the `matrix`, but the latter with the double line width:

```
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={line width=0.25pt, draw, minimum width=1.0cm, minimum height=1.0cm, inner sep=0, anchor=south west},
    mymatrix/.style={line width=0.5pt, draw, inner sep=0},
    myline/.style={shorten <=0.2pt, shorten >=0.2pt},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, mymatrix] (firstmatrix) at (0,0)
    {   q & w & e \\
        a & s & d \\ 
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a little problem with the linewidth between the nodes. You get double lines.

Comment: Hmmm.  Curious as to why you're using `matrix of nodes` and explicitly putting in the nodes.  Also, your lines will be off if the nodes are of noticeably different sizes.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21178/86 for a similar issue.

Comment: Dammit, it just struck me like a lightning: of cause the nodes are named `name-row-column`! D'oh! Thanks @AndrewStacey :D

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the *infamous* `\tikzmark` solution which allows one to compose the tables outside (or inside) of the `tikzpicture` environment, and mark the two points you want to connect, and then draw the arrow between them.

So, with the `c` data entry  defined as `c\tikzmark{left}`, and the `j` data entry is defined as `\tikzmark{right}j`, one can use `\DrawArrow[<draw_options>]{left}{right}` with different draw options to obtain:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\DrawArrow}[3][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = left point
    % #3 = right point
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [-latex, shorten <= 0.25cm, shorten >= 0.30cm, #1] ($(#2)+(0,0.5ex)$) to ($(#3)+(0,0.25ex)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}\hline
    a & b & c\tikzmark{left} \\\hline
    d & e & f \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace*{2.0cm}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}\hline
    g & h & i \\\hline
    \tikzmark{right}j & k & l \\\hline
\end{tabular}
%
\DrawArrow{left}{right}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an other idea based on *Peter Grill*'s answer (I didn't even think of using a `tabular` when writing my first answer, so thanks for reminding me that there are some non-TikZ constructs one could use). It doesn't use `\tikzmark` (which otherwise is awesome, but in my humble opinion not needed here) and puts the tabulars in `node`s instead, so you can use the degree notion (`node.degree`) to specify where to draw your arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\newcommand{\mytab}[2]% alignment, content
{   \begin{tabular}{#1}
        #2
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0] (one) {\mytab{|c|c|c|}{\hline g & h & i \\ \hline j & k & l \\ \hline}};
    \node[inner sep=0,right=2cm of one.east] (two) {\mytab{|c|c|c|}{\hline a & b & c \\ \hline d & e & f \\ \hline}};
    \draw[-latex] (one.15) to[out=0,in=180] (two.195);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]