# UML Statediagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I am trying to draw a UML statediagram with TikZ. I tried `tikz-uml`, but I was not satisfied with the way it handles the state nodes. While I love TikZ for its versatile placement options of nodes (relative placement with above, selecting anchor points), I have no clue how to do this with `tikz-uml`. Furthermore, it gives me text extending outside the node.

Looking briefly at `tikz-uml`'s implementation (I am still a TeX noob), I learned that actually a rounded rectangle is drawn around a title node and a content node with the `fitting` library, and subsequently a line separating the statename is added. Thus I tried to have an implementation of my own, drawing the title and the contents in one TikZ picture, which I then put inside a node. That way I hope to preserve the easy placement that I have grown accustomed to from normal TikZ nodes. Here is the code and the problem, the line I draw for separation is misplaced above the nodes (note: render twice to get the same line placement I got):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}   
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}   
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, rounded corners](box){
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \node[draw=red](caption) {titel};
            \node[below=0 of caption] {\begin{tabular} ccontent\\more content\end{tabular}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \draw (caption.south -| box.west) -- (caption.south -| box.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To show where the line should be, the title box is drawn in red, the line should be on its lower edge, similar to the `tikz-uml` output. The line actually is the black bar above the outer black node, drawn above it near the top edge of the image.

[image: line misplaced above box]

---

For comparison here is what I tried with `tikz-uml` and the result (simply replace everyting inside the outer tikzpicture above with this to test):

```
\begin{umlstate}[x=-3, y=-4, name=discard, do=clear all valid bits]{discard}
\end{umlstate}
```

[image: overset text with tikz uml]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a complete LaTeX document, that I can paste into my editor?

Comment: @JohnWickerson: done. I skipped it for the lower part, since it uses the same preamble on one hand, and I am not satisfied with the placement option tikz-uml gives me anyway on the other hand. Thansk for the grammar corrections, I hope I learned a thing or two.

Comment: No prob. By the way, if you write `do=clear all\\valid bits` then you can avoid the problem of the text extending outside the node.

Comment: My *guess* is that you should stick with the `tikz-uml` package, as it's probably the best tool for the job of writing UML diagrams. Can you give a specific example of the placement options that you're not satisfied with?

Comment: @JohnWickerson: I am not satisfied with the lack of relative placement (e.g. `below=1cm of myOtherUmlState`), at least I don't know how to apply it to `tikz-uml`. Furthermore I consider the forced linebreak a hack, wich should not be necessary since tikz can handle this nicly. I have to read up on it again, but I don't recall any prerequisites for nodes fitting the text placed inside. Furthermore I would appreciate placement at different anchors (I hava a decision with 5 outcomes and would like to place them in equal distance to the decision marker at 0, -45, -90, -135 and 180°)

Comment: @JohnWickerson: I am not sayinig I am not going to use all the fine nodes for History states decisions statart state, etc. . I am just looking for a better implementation of the state node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your state node into a 'multipart' node. For that, you need to load the `shapes.multipart` TikZ library. You should then be able to use all the placement options that you're used to.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}    
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, rounded corners]{%
      \tikz\node[draw=red, rectangle, rounded corners]{titel};
      \nodepart{two}
      \begin{tabular}{c}
      content \\ more content
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS. You might alternatively make your state node into a `matrix`, but then it's quite hard to get the horizontal line that you want (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/horizontal-row-separation-line-in-tikz-matrix-like-hline-in-tabular) discussion, for instance).

Comment: Looks awesome, this can be simplified, since I only had the redf rame to show were the lines was supposed to be. Thank you very much (I think the implementor of tikz-uml could improve his library with his approach(correct look, handling like a standard tikz node, and if simplified no more hassle than the tikz-uml state representation)).

Comment: btw. for people drawing statediagrams defining a style helps. Just put `[stateNode/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, rounded corners, fill=yellow!10}]` behind tikzpicture and use it with `\node[statenode]{...}`, I wonder if there is a shortcut for the `\nodepart{two}\tabular`-part since this gets tedious

Comment: You could probably factor that into a macro, say `\statenode`, such that the diagram in my answer could be obtained by writing `\statenode{titel}{content \\ more content}`.

Comment: the problem with a macro is not loosing tikz power... (adding positioning, nameing the nodes are most important and possible, but what about special cases like different fills, fancy decorations,...) (sort of forwarding), I am rather leaving this untouched (I am clueless as to how do proper forwarding, best would be a command that mimics a node (in alll ways), but has two textparameters.

Comment: Fair enough. Then maybe just factor out the *contents* of the state node into a macro: `\node[statenode]{\statenode{titel}{content \\ more content}}`.