# coloring every other row of a table, with vertical lines

Tags: tables, color

I am making a table that needs every other row colored.  I thought to use this.

```
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!15}
```

But my table has vertical bars

```
\begin{tabular}{r|*{3}{p{2in}|}}
```

as well as horizontal bars

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\ }
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Monday}  
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Wednesday}  
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Friday} \\ \hline
```

and the color makes them disappear (the bar from the "`r|`" stays as I have it above, but if I change the first multicolumn's "`\`" to "week" then this bar also disappears).  Am I missing something; is there a way to keep the bars and get the colors behind them?  (I have a 2010 TeX Live.)

Comment: that is always a problem with the pdf viewer. The printed output should be ok.

Comment: You could give the [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package a try.

Comment: I'm using beamer so the pdf viewer is where it will be seen.  I'll look at tabu, thanks.

Comment: The tabu package isn't showing the row in color at all for me; maybe I'm doing it wrong but I copied the rowcolors example from the manual.  I guess I'll stick with xcolor.  (I am using AcrobatReader9 on Ubuntu 11; I believe that I need AR because I do some other things that seem to me to require it.)  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Jim: Could you give a complete example of the kind of table you are trying to produce (ideally in a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), which will make it easier for people to try out the code and come up with solutions).

Answer (score 21):

Before this stays completely unanswered, may I propose a solution that won't appeal to purists, but that might be a good approach for you.

There have been a couple of questions concerned with how TikZ matrices can be used as replacements for tables: [TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular), [Horizontal row separation line in tikz matrix (like \hline in tabular)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/horizontal-row-separation-line-in-tikz-matrix-like-hline-in-tabular). Since you're using beamer, you have TikZ loaded already, so this wouldn't require additional packages.

You can use matrix options like `every even row/.style`,`every odd column/.style`, `row 1/.style` and so on to adjust the appearance of your tables. Here's an example based on the snippets in your question:

[image: tikz matrix as a table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        every even row/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!20}
        },
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=2em,font=\bfseries}
        },
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                font=\bfseries
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (first) [table,text width=6em]
{
& Monday   & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday\\
1   & A & B & C & D & E \\
2   & F & G & H & J & K \\
3   & A & B & C & D & E \\
4   & F & G & H & J & K \\
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was unaware of that option.  I'll check it out.

Comment: I really enjoyed your clear solution!

Comment: This is looking amazing. What I am missing in comparison to a regular `tabular` is the ability to set the width of the whole table and to have the columns automatically set their width based on the content.

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools specifically designed to address that kind of problem.

That package provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of `array`) but with tools to color rows, columns and cells with a perfect result in all PDF viewers, at all levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}cccccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15}
  \rowcolor{black}{1}
\Body
\RowStyle[color=white]{}
& Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday\\
1 & A & B & C & D & E \\
2 & F & G & H & J & K \\
3 & A & B & C & D & E \\
4 & F & G & H & J & K \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Encouraged by nice @F. Pantigny [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/coloring-every-other-row-of-a-table-with-vertical-lines/605260#605260) (+1) here is solution with use of the new `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {c},
             hlines,   vlines,
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!30},
             row{1}   = {bg=black,fg=white,font=\bfseries},
             }
    & Monday
        & Tuesday
            & Wednesday
                & Thursday
                    & Friday\\
 1  & A & B & C & D & E \\
 2  & F & G & H & J & K \\
 3  & A & B & C & D & E \\
 4  & F & G & H & J & K \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

After one compilation, the result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: When I look the resulting PDF with SumatraPDF (which uses MuPDF as PDF renderer) I see irregular vertical rules...

Comment: @F.Pantigny, you are right, however in the Reader this pdf viewer artifacts are not visible. Hopefully, your comment will read author of the package.

Comment: I think it is the correct result. We should draw vlines if the cells do not span multi columns.

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat Pro 2020, vertical rules disappear at some levels of zoom (and also in Sumatra PDF) and the question of the OP was: *how to avoid that problem*...