# Arrows for flowcharts

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, flow-charts

I have a question regarding the following flowchart: I would like to connect `decision-7` with the vertical line that comes from `block-1` "Schneiden und Ausbauen" and add an arrow. I would like to do the same with `block-1`. Connect it with the vertical line and have an arrow there to better understand the flowchart. So far none of my tries worked! Thanks four your help in advance

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,automata,positioning,fit,quotes}

\begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{decision} = [ diamond, aspect=2, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text centered, inner sep=0pt ]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [ rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=7em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em ]
    \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=110, trapezium right angle=110, text width=28em ,  minimum height=4em, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20]
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, text width=22em, minimum height=2em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [ draw, -latex' ]

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \small
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.50cm, auto]
        % place nodes
        \node [cloud, text width=10em] (init) {Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch} ;
        \node [decision, below=0.5cm of init] (decision-1) {sind Rohre bis zur projektierten Teufe frei?} ;
        \node [decision, below=0.5cm of decision-1] (decision-6) {hinter\-einander\-liegende einzementierte Rohre?} ;
        \node [right of=decision-6] (dummy20) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy20] (dummy21) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy21] (dummy22) {} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy22] (block-9) {separates Entfernen (Voll- und Sektionsfräsen) oder Multistrang-Sektionsfräsen} ;
        \node [right of=decision-1] (dummy1) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy1] (dummy2) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy2] (dummy8) {} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy8] (block-1) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;
        \node [decision, below=0.5cm of decision-6] (decision-2) {ZK > 60m oberhalb projekt. Teufe} ;
        \node [right of=decision-2] (dummy3) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy3] (dummy4) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy4] (dummy9) {} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy9] (block-2) {Sektionsfräsen} ;
        \node [block, below=0.5cm of decision-2] (block-3) {Schneiden und Ausbauen oberhalb der ZK-Teufe} ;
        \node [right of=block-3] (dummy11) {} ;
        \node [decision, below=0.5cm of block-3] (decision-3) {Rohre vollständig einzementiert?} ;
        \node [right of=decision-3] (dummy5) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy5] (dummy6) {} ;
        \node [right of=dummy6] (dummy10) {} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy10] (block-4) {Vollfräsen} ;
        \node [decision, above of=block-4] (decision-7) {erfolgreich?} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy11] (block-10) {Troubleshooting-Guide (siehe Tab.....; Abschätzung Alternativen} ;
        \node [block, below=0.5cm of decision-3] (block-5) {Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} ;
        \node [decision, below=0.5cm of block-5] (decision-4) {sind Rohre frei?} ;
        \node [block, below of=decision-4] (block-11) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;
        \node [right of=decision-4] (dummy7) {} ;
        \node [block, right of=dummy7] (block-6) {abschnittsweise schneiden} ;
        \node [block, above of=block-6] (block-7) {Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} ;
        \node [right of=block-7] (dummy11) {} ;
        \node [decision, right of=dummy11] (decision-5) {sind Rohre frei?} ;
        \node [block, below of=decision-5] (block-12) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;
        \node [cloud, text width=5em, below of=block-6] (block8) {Job beendet} ;
        % draw edges
        \path [line] (init) -- (decision-1) ;
        \path [line] (decision-1) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-1) ;
        \path [line] (decision-1) -- node [near start] {nein} (decision-6) ;
        \path [line] (decision-6) -- node [near start] {nein} (decision-2) ;
        \path [line] (decision-6) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-9) ;
        \path [line] (decision-2) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-2) ;
        \path [line] (decision-2) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-3) ;
        \path [line] (block-3) -- (decision-3) ;
        \draw [-to] (block-10.north) edge [bend left]  (decision-7.north west) ;
        \draw [-to] (block-9.east) edge [bend left]  (decision-7.north east) ;
        \path [line] (block-2) -- (decision-7) ;
        \path (block-1) -| ([xshift=1.0cm, yshift=0cm] block-1.east) |- (block8)  coordinate[pos=0.5] (a2);
        \path [line] (block-1) -| ([xshift=1.0cm, yshift=0cm] block-1.east) |- (block8) ;
        \path [line] (decision-7) -| node [near start] {ja} (a2) ;
        \path [line] (decision-3) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-4) ;
        \path [line] (decision-7.west) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-10.east) ;
        \path [line] (decision-3) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-5) ;
        \path [line] (block-5) -- (decision-4) ;
        \path [line] (decision-4) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-6) ;
        \path [line] (decision-4) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-11) ;
        \path [line] (block-11) -- (block8) ;
        \path [line] (decision-5) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-12) ;
        \path (block-12) |- (block8) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a1);
        \path [line] (block-12) -- (a1) ;
        \path [line] (block-12) |- (block8) ;
        \path [line] (block-6) -- (block-7) ;
        \path [line] (block-4) -- (decision-7) ;
        \path [line] (block-7) -- (decision-5) ;
        \path [line] (decision-5) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-4) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Verfahren zum Entfernen von Rohren]{möglicher Arbeitsablauf zum Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch} \label{VerfahrenRohr}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood you correctly, but see if this answers your question. The key thing is that I added a new coordinate `ur` (for "upper right") 1cm right of `block-1`. I then use perpendicular coordinates to draw the lines:

```
    % define a new coordinate
    \coordinate [right=1cm of block-1] (ur);

    % use the new coordinate to draw the arrows on the right side
    \path [line] (block-1) -- (ur);
    \path [line] (decision-7) -- node[near start] {ja} (decision-7 -| ur);
    \path [line] (ur) -- (block8 -| ur);
    \path [line] (block8 -| ur) -- (block8);
```

You had used `-|`/`|-` as path specifications, but you can also use it to define coordinates as shown above. That is, `(a -| b)` is the coordinate that has the y-coordinate of `a` and the x-coordinate of `b` (and vice versa for `(a |- b)`).

I also used that method to change how nodes are positioned, letting you avoid all those dummy nodes. You could also use a `\matrix` to do the positioning, would make sense for a diagram like this with three "columns" of nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes,
  arrows.meta, % supersedes arrows
  calc,automata,positioning,fit,quotes}


\tikzset{
  decision/.style={diamond, aspect=2, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text centered, inner sep=0pt},
  block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=7em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=110, trapezium right angle=110, text width=28em ,  minimum height=4em, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20},
  cloud/.style={draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, text width=22em, minimum height=2em, text centered},
  line/.style={draw, -Latex}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \footnotesize % changed to make diagram fit better in page
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm, auto]
    % place nodes
    \node [cloud, text width=10em] (init) {Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch} ;
    \node [decision, below=0.5cm of init] (decision-1) {sind Rohre bis zur projektierten Teufe frei?} ;
    \node [decision, below=0.5cm of decision-1] (decision-6) {hinter\-einander\-liegende einzementierte Rohre?} ;

    \node [block, right=4cm of decision-1] (block-1) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;

    \node [block, at={(block-1 |- decision-6)}] (block-9) {separates Entfernen (Voll- und Sektionsfräsen) oder Multistrang-Sektionsfräsen} ;

    \node [decision, below=0.5cm of decision-6] (decision-2) {ZK > 60m oberhalb projekt. Teufe} ;

    \node [block, at=(block-1 |- decision-2)] (block-2) {Sektionsfräsen} ;
    \node [block, below=0.5cm of decision-2] (block-3) {Schneiden und Ausbauen oberhalb der ZK-Teufe} ;
    \node [decision, below=0.5cm of block-3] (decision-3) {Rohre vollständig einzementiert?} ;

    \node [block, at=(block-1 |- decision-3)] (block-4) {Vollfräsen} ;
    \node [decision, above=of block-4] (decision-7) {erfolgreich?} ;
    \node [block, left=1cm of decision-7] (block-10) {Troubleshooting-Guide (siehe Tab.....; Abschätzung Alternativen} ;
    \node [block, below=0.5cm of decision-3] (block-5) {Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} ;
    \node [decision, below=0.5cm of block-5] (decision-4) {sind Rohre frei?} ;
    \node [block, below=of decision-4] (block-11) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;

    \node [block, at=(decision-4 -| block-10)] (block-6) {abschnittsweise schneiden} ;
    \node [block, above=of block-6] (block-7) {Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} ;

    \node [decision, at=(block-1 |- block-7)] (decision-5) {sind Rohre frei?} ;
    \node [block, below=of decision-5] (block-12) {Schneiden und Ausbauen} ;
    \node [cloud, text width=5em, at=(block-11 -| block-6)] (block8) {Job beendet} ;
    % draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (decision-1) ;
    \path [line] (decision-1) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-1) ;
    \path [line] (decision-1) -- node [near start] {nein} (decision-6) ;
    \path [line] (decision-6) -- node [near start] {nein} (decision-2) ;
    \path [line] (decision-6) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-9) ;
    \path [line] (decision-2) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-2) ;
    \path [line] (decision-2) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-3) ;
    \path [line] (block-3) -- (decision-3) ;
    % changed "edge" to "to"
    \draw [-Latex] (block-10.north) to [bend left]  (decision-7.north west) ;
    \draw [-Latex] (block-9.east) to [bend left]  (decision-7.north east) ;
    \path [line] (block-2) -- (decision-7) ;

    % define a new coordinate
    \coordinate [right=1cm of block-1] (ur);

    % use the new coordinate to draw the arrows on the right side
    \path [line] (block-1) -- (ur);
    \path [line] (decision-7) -- node[near start] {ja} (decision-7 -| ur);
    \path [line] (ur) -- (block8 -| ur);
    \path [line] (block8 -| ur) -- (block8);


    \path [line] (decision-3) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-4) ;
    \path [line] (decision-7.west) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-10.east) ;
    \path [line] (decision-3) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-5) ;
    \path [line] (block-5) -- (decision-4) ;
    \path [line] (decision-4) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-6) ;
    \path [line] (decision-4) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-11) ;
    \path [line] (block-11) -- (block8) ;
    \path [line] (decision-5) -- node [near start] {ja} (block-12) ;

    \path [line] (block-12) -- (block-12 |- block8) ;

    \path [line] (block-6) -- (block-7) ;
    \path [line] (block-4) -- (decision-7) ;
    \path [line] (block-7) -- (decision-5) ;
    \path [line] (decision-5) -- node [near start] {nein} (block-4) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Verfahren zum Entfernen von Rohren]{möglicher Arbeitsablauf zum Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch} \label{VerfahrenRohr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for kicks, here is one approach using a `\matrix`, as mentioned earlier. I borrowed a method from [How to have a specific style for empty cells in a tikz matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386793/how-to-have-a-specific-style-for-empty-cells-in-a-tikz-matrix/386828#386828) for setting the styles for the various cells.  I also used several `\foreach` to draw the arrows, to cut down on code a bit. This was mainly intended as a demo, I haven't added much in the way of explanations. If of interest, I can do that, where necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes,
  arrows.meta,
  positioning,
  quotes,
  matrix
}


\tikzset{
  decision/.style={diamond, aspect=2, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text centered, inner sep=0pt},
  block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=7em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
  cloud/.style={draw, ellipse, fill=red!20, text width=22em, minimum height=2em, text centered},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  arrow/.style={-Latex},
  edgelabel/.style={font=\scriptsize, near start},
  % borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386828
  setblocks/.style args = {(#1,#2)}{%
    row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={block}}},
  setdecisions/.style args = {(#1,#2)}{%
    row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={decision}}},
  setclouds/.style args = {(#1,#2)}{%
    row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={cloud}}}
]
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  name=m,
  every node/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    anchor=center
  },
  row sep=4mm,
  setclouds/.list={(1,1),(9,2)},
  setdecisions/.list={(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(6,1),(8,1),(5,3),(7,3)},
  setblocks/.list={(5,1),(7,1),(9,1),(5,2),(7,2),(8,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(6,3),(8,3)}
] {
% first row
% set column sep individually here, note [<length>] after each &
%
% |[...]| is used to append style options to a cell
% hence, another way to set e.g. the block style for a cell is to use |[block]| at the start of the cell
|[text width=8em]| Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch &[1mm]  &[7mm]  \\
% second row
sind Rohre bis zur projektierten Teufe frei? & &
Schneiden und Ausbauen \\
% third
hinter\-einander\-liegende einzementierte Rohre? & &
separates Entfernen (Voll- und Sektionsfräsen) oder Multistrang-Sektionsfräsen \\
% fourth row
ZK > 60m oberhalb projekt. Teufe &&
Sektionsfräsen \\
% fifth row
Schneiden und Ausbauen oberhalb der ZK-Teufe &
Troubleshooting-Guide (siehe Tab.....; Abschätzung Alternativen & 
erfolgreich? \\
% sixth row
Rohre vollständig einzementiert? &&
Vollfräsen \\
% seventh row
% need braces here so that the \\ doesn't end the matrix row
{Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} &
{Zugversuch \\ Frei\-punkt\-be\-stimmung} &
sind Rohre frei? \\
% eigth row
sind Rohre frei? &
abschnittsweise schneiden &
Schneiden und Ausbauen \\
% last row
Schneiden und Ausbauen &
|[text width=5em]| Job beendet &
|[coordinate]| \\
};

\coordinate [right=1cm of m-2-3] (ur);
\coordinate (ll) at (ur |- m-9-2);

% draw arrows in first column
\foreach [count=\i from 2, remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] \txt in {,nein,nein,nein,,nein,,ja}
   \draw [arrow] (m-\j-1) to["\txt"edgelabel] (m-\i-1);

% the four arrows going from col 1 to col 3
\foreach \row in {2,3,4,6}
   \draw [arrow] (m-\row-1) to["ja"edgelabel] (m-\row-3);

% remaining arrows without labels
\foreach \start/\stop in {4-3/5-3,6-3/5-3,7-2/7-3,8-2/7-2,8-3/9-3,9-1/9-2}
   \draw [arrow] (m-\start) -- (m-\stop);

% arrows with labels
\foreach \start/\stop/\txt in {
   5-3/5-2/nein,
   7-3/6-3/nein,
   7-3/8-3/ja,
   8-1/8-2/nein,
   8-1/9-1/ja}
   \draw [arrow] (m-\start) to["\txt"edgelabel] (m-\stop);

% curved arrows
\draw [arrow] (m-5-2) to[bend left] (m-5-3.north west);
\draw [arrow] (m-3-3.east) to[bend left] (m-5-3.north east);

% remaining arrows
\foreach \start/\stop in {
   m-2-3/ur,
   ur/ll,
   ll/m-9-2}
  \draw [arrow] (\start) -- (\stop);

\draw [arrow] (m-5-3) to["ja"edgelabel] (m-5-3 -| ur);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Verfahren zum Entfernen von Rohren]{möglicher Arbeitsablauf zum Entfernen von Rohren aus dem Bohrloch} \label{VerfahrenRohr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: arrows around decision "erfolgreich? not seems to be logical. for "ja" is more sensible to be in opposite direction, bend ones only in one direction (to decision) ... nice work! (+1)

Comment: @Zarko I didn't consider the logic of this at all, you're probably right. Thanks. Edited.