# Example of fancy table using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Can anyone share me several fancy table templates? I want to make this thread like a reference so that each time I need a template, I could just go here. If you can, please provide a screenshot for illustrative purpose. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: have you tried googling? this one pops up readily: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-table/

Comment: Yeah, I found these two tables. However my goal is not just two, I want the whole collection so that I can look it up later.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's an example which I wrote for my [TeX blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-table/). It defines a `matrixtable` environment which uses the TikZ `matrix of nodes` feature.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading]%
  [top=blue!1,bottom=blue!30]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*\up{\textcolor{YellowGreen}{$\blacktriangle$}}
\newcommand*\down{\textcolor{Red}{$\blacktriangledown$}}
\newcommand*\const{\textcolor{darkgray}{\textbf{--}}}
\newcommand*\head[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newenvironment{matrixtable}[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[matrix of nodes/.style={
    execute at begin cell=\node\bgroup\strut,
    execute at end cell=\egroup;}]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,top color=blue!20,
    bottom color=blue!80,draw=white,
    nodes={draw,top color=blue!10,bottom color=blue!35,
    draw,inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3.1ex},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=0.6ex,inner sep=2ex,
    rounded corners,column 1/.style={minimum width=#1},
    column 2/.style={minimum width=#2},
    column 3/.style={minimum width=#3},
    column 4/.style={minimum width=#4}]}%
{;\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,bg=lightgray]
\begin{center}
\begin{matrixtable}{1.2cm}{2.4cm}{1.2cm}{0.6cm}{
  \head{Rank}   & \head{Distribution} & \head{Hits} & \\
  1 & Ubuntu    & 2114 & \down  \\
  2 & Fedora    & 1451 & \up    \\
  3 & Mint      & 1297 & \const \\
  4 & OpenSUSE  & 1228 & \up    \\
  5 & Debian    & 910  & \down  \\
  6 & Mandriva  & 907  & \up    \\
  7 & PCLinuxOS & 764  & \up    \\
  8 & Puppy     & 738  & \up    \\
  9 & Sabayon   & 671  & \up    \\
 10 & Arch      & 625  & \down  \\
}
\end{matrixtable}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy table example]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For some reason it wasn't compiling off the bat. I made a variant without beamer and slightly different symbol for no-change: http://pastebin.com/GnZi7sdY

Answer (score 35):

The table from my answer to [coloring every other row of a table, with vertical lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/coloring-every-other-row-of-a-table-with-vertical-lines) is not extremely fancy, but could come in useful in some cases:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        every even row/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!20}
        },
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=2em,font=\bfseries}
        },
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                font=\bfseries
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (first) [table,text width=6em]
{
& Monday   & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday\\
1   & A & B & C & D & E \\
2   & F & G & H & J & K \\
3   & A & B & C & D & E \\
4   & F & G & H & J & K \\
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wait, why I find that in the first row, the texts are not really centred. Did you notice that?

Comment: Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log. ``{
& Monday   & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday\    1   & A & B & C & D & E \    2   & F & G & H & J & K \    3   & A & B & C & D & E \    4   & F & G & H & J & K \    };`` this line has error

Comment: @fairytale -- at some point in the past, there was a mass "adjustment" to the entire site, which eliminated the second backslash and line break from many hundreds, even thousands, of questions and answers.  we're doing our best to repair the mess.  see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7168 for the sad story.

Answer (score 17):

Another example, which combines a `tabularx` environment with a TikZ picture, drawing on its background layer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading]%
  [top=blue!1,bottom=blue!30]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newcommand*\up{\textcolor{green}{%
  \ensuremath{\blacktriangle}}}
\newcommand*\down{\textcolor{red}{%
  \ensuremath{\blacktriangledown}}}
\newcommand*\const{\textcolor{darkgray}%
  {\textbf{--}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[bg=lightgray]
\textbf{\Large Linux distribution ranking,
        26th August 2009}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (tbl) {
\begin{tabularx}{.6\textwidth}{cXrcc}
\arrayrulecolor{purple}
\textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Distribution} &
  \textbf{Hits} & \\
1 & Ubuntu\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}  &  2114 & \down \\
\midrule
2 & Fedora & 1451 & \up \\
\midrule
3 & Mint & 1297 & \const \\
\midrule
4 & OpenSUSE & 1228 & \up \\
\midrule
5 & Debian & 910 & \down \\
\midrule
6 & Mandriva & 907 & \up \\
\midrule
7 & PCLinuxOS & 764 & \up \\
\midrule
8 & Puppy & 738 & \up \\
\midrule
9 & Sabayon & 671 & \up \\
\midrule
10 & Arch & 625 & \down \\[0.5ex]
\end{tabularx}};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[rounded corners,top color=red,bottom color=black,
    draw=white] ($(tbl.north west)+(0.14,0)$)
    rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0.13,0.9)$);
\draw[rounded corners,top color=white,bottom color=black,
    middle color=red,draw=blue!20] ($(tbl.south west)
    +(0.12,0.5)$) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)-(0.12,0)$);
\draw[top color=blue!1,bottom color=blue!20,draw=white]
    ($(tbl.north east)-(0.13,0.6)$)
    rectangle ($(tbl.south west)+(0.13,0.2)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\small
Data by DistroWatch.com, spanning over the last 6 months,
hits per day.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy table example]

Comment: I use fancy chapter from http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/, the chapter is in example memoir chapter style (documentation 2010) too and I customize some. the result is great. thanks Stefan Kottwitz.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: IMHO that one is the best of the examples. But maybe you could change the text color of the head, because black text on red to black color gradient is unreadable.