# 'Internal borders' in table cells

Tags: tables

I am looking to add borders to some cells in a table, such that the borders surround the contents and there is a space between each cell. The best image I could find that shows sort of what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

This is possible in HTML via the `cellspacing` setting in tables. How can I achieve the same in LaTeX? I would only want a few of the table cells to have this internal border, not all of them.

The closest I have come is by using `fbox`, but I couldn't get them to extend all the way to the edges of the table cells.

Comment: have a look at [Example of fancy table using TikZ package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28087)

Answer (score 6):

For simple tables an easy solution is the `hhline` package, but I think that **is not** a good solution for complex tables with `\multiwrow` and `\multicolumn` cells, as showed in your question.

In this MWE are showed both problems:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{black} 
\doublerulesepcolor{gray!40} 
\begin{tabular}{||>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}\bfseries}c||c||c||c||c||}
\hhline{|t:=:t:=:t:=:t:=:t:=:t|}
\rowcolor{red!30}
\multirow{2}{*}{alfa} & \bfseries beta & \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\bfseries beta} & \bfseries alfa \\
\hhline{||~|:=::=::=::=:|}
& beta & alfa & beta & alfa \\
\hhline{|:=::=::=::=::=:|}
alfa & beta & alfa & beta & alfa \\
\hhline{|:=::=::=::=::=:|}
alfa & beta & alfa & beta & alfa \\
\hhline{|:=::=::=::=::=:|}
\rowcolor{green!30} gamma & delta & gamma & delta & gamma \\
\hhline{|b:=:b:=:b:=:b:=:b:=:b|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put `multirow` in the second row: `           & \bfseries beta & \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\bfseries beta} & \bfseries alfa \\hhline{||~|:=::=::=::=:|}
\multirow{-2}{*}{alfa}& beta & alfa & beta & alfa \\ ` so that the text doesn't get clipped.

Comment: @HarishKumar, yes, much better in this way. But the multirow cell still have 3 colors. Too much for my taste!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicemtrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\B}
  { 
    \Block
      [  
        tikz = clip ,
        tikz = { draw, line width=3pt } ,
        tikz = { draw, color = gray!10, line width = 2.5pt}
      ]
  }

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=5pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}ccccc}
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor{lightgray}
  \rectanglecolor{white}{3-2}{6-5}
\Body
  \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
  \B{2-1}{Question} & \B{1-2}{Women} && \B{1-2}{Men} \\
  & \B{}{Yes} & \B{}{No} & \B{}{Yes} & \B{}{No} \\
  \B{}{Question 1} & \B{}{42\%} & \B{}{58\%} & \B{}{61\%} & \B{}{39\%} \\
  \B{}{Question 2} & \B{}{53\%} & \B{}{47\%} & \B{}{69\%} & \B{}{31\%} \\
  \B{}{Question 3} & \B{}{26\%} & \B{}{74\%} & \B{}{51\%} & \B{}{49\%} \\
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}
  \B{}{Average}    & \B{}{40\%} & \B{}{60\%} & \B{}{60\%} & \B{}{40\%} 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several compilations.