# Multi-row and Multi-column text alignment and grid

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to create the table below using tabular in latex.

[image]

Exploring the stack exchange for similar problems [like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308590/using-multi-row-and-multi-column-for-table) has brought me to my current table:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Confusion Matrix}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline\vline
      \multirow{1}{*}{N=986}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Predicted} \\%
      \cline{3-4}
        \multirow{1}{*}{}
           & No & Yes\\%
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Actual}
        & \multirow{1}{*}{No} & TN = 27 & FP = 176\\%
        \cline{2-4}
        & \multirow{1}{*}{Yes} & FN = 9 &  TP = 174\\%
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \label{tab:confusion-matrix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

So far, this code produces the given table:

[image]

Now, how what should I change in order to make sure that `N=986` would occupy a cell merging the first 2 rows and columns, while `Predicted` occupies Row 1 and Columns 3 & 4, while `No` and `Yes` occupies the Row 2 and Columns 3 & 4 respectively? I have already tried to play around with the code but this one was the closest that I got to the intended output.

P.S.
I am also unsure why the vline is not there in the rightmost part of the first two cells. I am really having quite a trouble with table manipulation with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after removing unnecessary `multirow`s and `\vline`, and adding missed ampersand:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab:confusion-matrix}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{N=986}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Predicted}    \\
    \cline{2-4}
    &   & No & Yes                      \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Actual}
    &   No  &   TN = 27 & FP = 176      \\
  \cline{2-4}
    &   Yes &   FN = 9 &  TP = 174      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make `N = 986` be merged to Column 2 while `Predicted` only occupies columns 3 and 4?

Comment: I also checked the link that you commented earlier and I just wanted to say that that was neat!

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\captionsetup{skip = 0pt, font = sc}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline%\vline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \multirowcell{2.2}{N=986}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries Predicted} \\%
  \cline{3-4}
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \thead{No} & \thead{Yes}\\%
  \hline
  \multirowcell{2.7}{\bfseries Actual}
    & \thead{No} & TN = 27 & FP = 176\\%
    \cline{2-4}
    & \thead{Yes} & FN = 9 & TP = 174\\%
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:confusion-matrix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already settled with @Zarko's answer above with a few modifications that I applied. However, this solution is also pretty neat! Thank you!