# Automated table for excercise points in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, loops

I'm a computer science student. And I write most of my excercises in LaTeX.
So I often have to create a table for excercise points, with different numbers of excercises and different amounts of points for each excercise.

Therefor I want to define a command to do this very quickliy.
The idea is to provide a command `\excercisepoints{4,5,3}` which would print
a table table containing space for 3 excercises. Where the first gives 4 points, the seccond
5 points, and so on.

As well I want a row for the sum of points.
Because I really like TikZ I decided to do this in TikZ.

By using these three questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28087/example-of-fancy-table-using-tikz-package), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix)) I came to this:

```
\documentclass[class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                font=\bfseries
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\excercisepoints}[1]{
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach[count=\c] \i in {#1} {
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\c \& \i \& \\}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (first) [ampersand replacement=\&, table,text width=6em]
{
Excercise \& Maximal \& Achieved\\
\mymatrixcontent
$\sum$ \& \&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\excercisepoints{2,4,3}
\end{document}
```

This yields to this result:

[image: Output]

So there are two problems:

1. `\i` is not interpreted as a varible inside `\expandafter{}`
2. I don't know how to sum up the numbers. I already tried this with tikz.
   But I just found commands for summing up dimensions, not natural numbers.

**EDIT:**

For anybody watching these later, this is the working macro:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                font=\bfseries
            }
        }
    }
}
\newcommand{\punkteliste}[1]{%
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\def\mySum{0}
\foreach[count=\c] \i in {#1} {%
    \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\c \noexpand\& \i \noexpand\& \noexpand\\}%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\mySum+\i)}\global\let\mySum\pgfmathresult
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (first) [ampersand replacement=\&, table,text width=6em]
{
Excercise \& Maximal \& Achieved\\
\mymatrixcontent
$\sum$ \& \mySum \&\\
};
```

Comment: Does `\xappto\mymatrixcontent{\c \noexpand\& \i \noexpand\& \noexpand\\}%` do what you want? For the sum, you can either use PGF math or (La)TeX count(er)s, if it's just summarizing integers. For PGF math: Before the `\foreach` loop set a macro to `0` (`\def\mySum{0}`), inside the loop use `\pgfmathparse{\mySum+\i}\global\let\mysum\pgfmathresult`.(By the way, your `\exercisepoints` macro needs two more `%`, after the opening braces `{`.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks to you. My first problem is solved and the seccond neraly. The last remaining problem is, that for the above example 9.0 instead of 9 is the result. If you can solve this last problem and explain why this works (and mine not), then I would accept this as an answer. Aswell I saw the `%`many times behind the `{`, but never understood why. Where can I find the reason?

Comment: Ah, yes, you will need to use either `int()` or `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. In this case, `\pgfmathparse{int(\mySum+\i)}` is probably easier. The `\let` is necessary either way.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Anyway, I would really like to learn more about the usage of \let, \def, ... And other things which are usefull when defining commands in LaTeX. Is there any good tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to my comments, there is also the `/pgf/number format/int detect` option for `\pgfmathprintnumber`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=green,
            text width=6em,
            minimum width=6em+0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
            align=center
        },
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
%                font=\bfseries
            }
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\excercisepoints}[1]{%
    \let\mymatrixcontent\empty
    \def\mySum{0}%
    \foreach[count=\c] \i in {#1} {%
        \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\c \noexpand\& \i \noexpand\& \noexpand\\}%
        \pgfmathparse{\mySum+\i}
        \global\let\mySum\pgfmathresult
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (first) [ampersand replacement=\&, table]
    {
    \bfseries Excercise \& \bfseries Maximal \& \bfseries Achieved\\
    \mymatrixcontent
    $\sum$ \& \pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\mySum} \&\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\excercisepoints{2,4,3}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]