# How to achieve double border line between some columns of tikz matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I've read
[TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18521/tikz-matrix-as-a-replacement-for-tabular)
which nicely explained how to get table with borders in the first place.

Now, I'd like to have let's say thicker border (or double border line) between 2 & 3 columns of my multicolumn matrix. As far as I understand *column sep* is specified for entire matrix. So is it possible to mimic at least appearance of different border between some columns?

I want this to visually show on example how data was normalized in DB and I want to separate [superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey) from other columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise the distance between columns when you're writing the first row of your matrix. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=3em}]
{
0   &[-\pgflinewidth]   3 &[5mm]    6 \\
1   &                   1 &         3 \\
2   &                   2 &         9 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gets you this:

[image]

Note that I have used the answer from the question linked in this question as a template, but I've kept it simple to highlight the column separations.

Comment: This works! However I don't see default _column sep_ besides _row sep_ that you have. I guess it is necessary if there are many columns and one is lazy to explicitly specify separation after each ampersand sign.

What I wonder is that when I add supposedly default _column sep_ that it affects visually the distance between columns. Do they add up (default & after _&_ sign) or something?

Comment: The effect seems to be additive.